# Get MouseEvents while MousePressed

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have several QML Items that all have Mouse Areas.

What I want to achieve is:

- Click one of the items and start tracking the mouse
- Add every other Item that the mouse enters into a list
- End the tracking once the mouse is released

Sample Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width:500; height: 200;
    Rectangle{
        anchors.left: parent.left
        color: 'red'
        width: 200; height: 200;

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onReleased: console.log('onReleased red')
            onEntered:  console.log('onEntered red')
            onPressed:  {
                console.log('onPressed red')
                mouse.accepted = false
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        anchors.right: parent.right
        color: 'blue'
        width: 200; height: 200;

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onReleased: console.log('onReleased blue')
            onEntered:  console.log('onEntered blue')
            onPressed:  console.log('onPressed blue')
        }
    }
}
```

Expected behaviour:

- Click one Rectangle
- Get on entered event if I enter the other element
- Get the Released event

The sample code has both Version I tried, with and without accepting the `mousePressed` event.

What happens is:
If I press the mouse over one rectangle I do not get the `onEnter` event for all my other rectangles. 
If I do not accept the `onPressed` event, I get the `onEnter` Events but not the `onReleased` event.

**Note:**

I already found [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032143/qml-mousearea-mouseevent-issue) which uses a DropArea as workaround which is not what I want to use if there is any other solution.

Even though the Example may look like Drag&Drop it is not what I want. 
Please see the "What I want to achieve" at the top of this Question.

Comment: What kind of items?

Comment: Is your item placed one over other? Add some sourse code to the post. Try [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) link, it may be helpful.

Comment: @folibis The items do not overlap. I already tried to use one MouseArea that includes all other items but this didnt work either. The documentation is only about composed events which I do not use. I will add some source code later!

Comment: Added a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: Ok, as I understand you describe exactly drag'n'drop action.

Comment: No, I do not want drag&drop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve what you want just using standart *MouseArea* components. Standart QML components are kinda limited in their functionality.
What you have to do is to create your own *MouseArea* component through QML extension.
In our project we also encountered lots of problems with mouse handling, so how we managed to do it was:

1. Subclassed QQuickItem, and inside of this class we just tracked the mouse movement, and mouse buttons states. One important thing wass to install EventFilters defined by this class.
2. In QML, created a Simple Component that Checks if mouse is inside of currrent component.

If you need, i could post also a code here so you have an idea.
The implementation is not the prettiest, but it works

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! That sounds like a good solution, I would prefer a QML only Answer but this is much cleaner than misusing Drag&Drop. I do not need the Code but maybe it will be helpful to others in the future? I will wait a day more and see if somebody comes up with a pure qml way of doing this (maybe something was changed in newer Qt Versions?), if not I will definitely accept your answer. Thanks!